# how stack memory can be used?

Tags: c#, memory-management, stack

In stack the memory can be stored in a LIFO manner then 
 I will show u an example to explain my question clearly

```
public static void main()
{
  int i=0;
  char ch='a';
  string s="doubt";
}
```

In this above example first stack stores 'i' value and on the top of that stores 'ch' value and on the top of that 's' value stores. Now the question is if I want to use 'i' value how can it be popped out. If it pops all the variables to get int 'i' value, where are the 's' and 'ch' values, can be stored

Comment: Welcome to SO. You are lacking a language tag (if you think of Java, please add the `java` tag). So please **edit your question** to improve it (at least, add the appropriate tag for some *specific* programming language). Read also about the [call stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack)...

Comment: Ok thank u Basile Starynkevitch

Answer (score 1):

[Java](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_(programming_language)) implementations generally compile source code to some [JVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine) bytecode. [C#](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_(programming_language)) implementations compile for the [CLI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Language_Infrastructure), that is to [CLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Language_Runtime) bytecode called [CIL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language).

The JVM [bytecode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_bytecode) is for a stack based machine. The CIL bytecode is also [stack-based](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack-oriented_programming_language). So both JVM & CIL bytescodes target some [stack machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_machine) (but a different one for Java -i.e.JVM- and for C# -i.e. CIL-).

The compiler would compute the set of local variables and generate appropriate instructions to deal with the current frame in the [call stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack).

Conceptually, the slot (in that current call frame) for a local variable is popped when the control flow gets out of the [block](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_(programming)) declaring it (but what happens in reality is an implementation detail). Read about [scope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)). So you don't need to explicitly pop any value (the compiler takes care of nested scopes and local variables).

Quite often, a call frame is pushed (on the call stack) during call in the [function prologue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_prologue) and is popped (from the call stack) in the (corresponding) function epilogue, but the details depend upon the [calling conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention).

The JVM requires a [garbage collector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_(computer_science)) and so does the CIL. It would scan the pointers (to objects) on the stack (in your example `s`)

BTW, Java has some [reflection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_(computer_programming)) facilities (not for newbies) which may give access to the call stack. See [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/methodInvocation.html). C# (and the CIL) also provides [reflection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/reflection). Read also about [continuations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation).

The call stack is indeed a [stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(abstract_data_type)) following a [*last-in first-out*](http://www.allisons.org/ll/AlgDS/Stack/) discipline, but the pull and pop operations are part of the calling protocol and are compiler generated so remain implicit. During a call, a new call frame is pushed on the call stack. When returning, it is popped off the call stack. Read also about [tail-calls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call) (then at call time the new call frame is *replacing* the current one); sadly the JVM don't support tail-calls in general.

I recommend reading [SICP](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/) which has some chapters explaining these notions. It is an excellent freely available introduction to programming (which does *not* use Java or C# as its programming language).

Comment: You might want to mention that, inside the function, the local variables can be directly accessed (through the stack frame) - IMO this is what OP is confused about ("if i want to use 'i' value how can it be popped out"). See @EJPs answer ("it is accessed via an index")

Comment: @AndreasFester: of course local variables can be directly accessed (e.g. by further references to `i`  in the OP's example)

Comment: Exactly - you partially mentioned it ("dont need to explicitly pop") - just thought it might be even clearer to mention that they *still* can be accessed directly (means, not only through push/pop like in a "pure" stack). In OP's example, "s" and "ch" are still there, at the same location, but "i" is just accessed directly

Comment: Thank u that is a very good explanation and i have a doubt if it is accessing directly then why they are saying stack memory follows LIFO manner.Can u please answer my doubt!!

Answer (score 1):

> In this above example first stack stores 'i' value and on the top of that stores 'ch' value and on the top of that 's' value stores.

Correct. Note that you didn't say 'push', which would not have been correct.

> Now the question is if i want to use 'i' value how can it be popped out.

It isn't 'popped out'. It is accessed via an index from the current stack frame base.

> If if pops all the variables to get int 'i' value

It doesn't.

> where are the 's' and 'ch' values can be stored

On the stack, or better still in the current stack frame.

You should think of the stack as a stack of stack *frames*, one per method invocation, rather than as a value stack.

Comment: Ok its a good explanation but i am little confused with it and my confusion is "if the values are accessed directly why all of them are saying that the stack memory stores data in the stack format like LIFO?"

Comment: Because, as I already carefully explained in my answer, it is a stack of stack *frames*.